# Wetzel's 'occurences'

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-language, symbolic-logic

I was reading this [often quoted article by Linda Wetzel (1993)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30226498) where she discusses the 'occurence' of expressions in others and Quine's issues with the idea, she describes an expression as a sequence of symbols. If an expression can be a sequence of other expressions as well as a sequence of letters, how can both of these be true, defining a sentence as two separate things, mathematically speaking I would not define a sequence of letters as being also a sequence of words (a sequence with a sequence of letters at each position).

Perhaps I am misunderstanding here, but is she drawing a distinction between occurences in the string and occurences in the sentence as a type? I don't see how a sequence of letters and a sequence of words can be the same object as the function is different.

A function that takes a natural number to a letter, is different to a function that takes a natural number to a sequence of letters.

If 'expressions' are both strings of symbols how can one 'occur' within another? I find it a contradiction that an expression can occur within the other with the other retaining the same 'occurences' of symbols as it had before.

**How can an 'expression' be a sequence of letters and a sequence of other sequences?**

Comment: I haven't read Wetzel's papers but IMO there is no issue here... We start with an *alphabet*, i.e. a collection (usually finite) of symbols: **a,b,c,...,w,x,y,z**. Then we define *expression* i.e. a string (usually finite) of symbols: **mother**. If we work in a formal setting, we use also the empty space " " ("blank") as a symbol. In this way we have single words, like **mother** and **yes** and "complex" expressions (sentences), like **Ann is the mother of John** and **Yes**.

Comment: IMO there is no contradiction: what counts as a sentence is defined by the rules of the syntax (the *grammar*). Compare with logic: in propositional logic an *atom* **p** (a single symbol) can be a formula (a sentence), while in predicate logic a *term* **x** (a variable, i.e. a symbol) cannot be a formula.

Comment: Maybe useful: Linda Wetzel, [Types and Tokens: On Abstract Objects (MIT Press, 2009)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Types_and_Tokens/jNATqWe3B3sC)

Comment: As often (alas!) in philosophy we have to try to avoid discussing about "words", i.e. I prefer to start with clearly (as much as possible) defined terms. We have *symbols* and we have strings of symbols; if we think like natural language, we call *expressions* those strings that are meaningful, i.e. well-formed according to the rule of the grammar. Thus, **abc** is a string but not an expression while **one** is a string that is also an expression.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think the best definition of any elements of language is that they are all just sequences of symbols, I think discussing other elements 'occuring' in each other causes trouble.

Comment: The [Types vs Tokens](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/types-tokens/) introduced by Peirce is interesting but also problematic... It does not coincide with Universal-Particular, also if types are presumably universal and tokens must be particulars. In addition, it seems to me difficult to apply it outside the context of language: me and you are particulars (individuals) and we may assume for the discussion that we are both instances of the universal *man*; but I'm not a token of a "Mauro-type".

Comment: Having said that, probably we have a word-token "rose" that occurs in the sentence-token "A rose is a rose is a rose" as well as a word word "rose" that occurs (once?) in the corresponding sentence-type...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA by biggest issue with the whole thing is that I feel for something to 'occur' in something else it has to be at a higher level of abstraction then the thing it occurs in, perhaps it is me thinking of universals vs particulars, but it feels strange for a string to 'occur' in another string, if we thing of all strings as individual types with their own tokens it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find your aforementioned quotes about sentences, but if we take what Wetzel says on p218: "An expression is any sequence of letters; the wffs will be a proper subset of them" then this should be fairly simple. Now it is easy to realize that every sequence of words naturally gives rise to a sequence of letters over the typical alphabet + whitespace/delimiters.

So Wetzel is not defining a sentence as two contradictory things, she is realizing a subset relation. However, you should also in general be aware of the following:

Suppose we wish to form all words. We fix a base class of letters and close it under the proper grammatical rules. This process is entirely analagous to fixing a base class of words, and, using the grammatical rules for sentences, obtaining all the sentences. So when dealing with formal expressions, it is common to conflate the words "word", "sentence", "wff", etc.

This allows Wetzel to define a notion of occurence for both word and sentence, allowing context to determine which is the case. This is standard in mathematics and philosophy, although less common in linguistics, where the distinction actually matters.

Lastly, with respect to your last point, there is no contradiction in a word occuring in another, whilst both retain the same association with whatever sequence they have been associated with. In fact, it has to be this way. Example:

Bob said "Sarah is a bad person".

Both of these are sentences, one containing the other. The fact that one is embedded in the other should not change eithers order at all.

Comment: You say 'every sequence of words gives rise to a sequence of letters', perhaps this is my mistake, I think the sequence of words and sequence of letters are one and the same? So for every 'sentence' it can be associated with a sequence of letters? However the sequence of 'words' and sequence of letters are different. I don't know if I'm being too 'mathematical' about this but a sequence with different objects in each position are different sequences I believe.

Comment: @Confused can you please provide the exact page number where Wetzel says that "sentences are sequences of words"? I think this will help clarify our discussion.

Comment: Maybe page 215: "is. In *On Universals* Wolterstorff says that "occurrences of sentences [words or sequences of words] are Peirce's tokens"."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA its unclear to me that Wetzel endorses this view, since that very same paragraph then deduces an impossibility from Wolterstorffs view in conjunction with Pierces. Further, I don't see the word 'sentence' anywhere else in her paper, which leads me to think Confused is referencing some other paper.

Comment: Upon re-reading, I think I have mis-understood, however 'Wetzel' still talks about  * as being an expression and also mentions expressions occuring in one another, as well as letters occuring in expressions, using the idea of a sequence for both, which is the primary issue I have, how can an 'expression' be a sequence of other expressions and also a sequence of letters? But definitely there is holes somewhere in my thinking.

Comment: @Confused Wetzel explains exactly this on page 219

Comment: @Confused - but yes, letters form words and words form sentences and sentences form texts.

Comment: If you equate *expression* with finite string of symbols, then words and sentences and texts are all expressions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA my issue is essentially this (I'm sorry I cannot express it better' : any word consists of it's 'own' occurences of the letters, the sentence has it's 'own' occurences of words, yet the sentence also has occurences of letters, each occurence of the 'word' has it's own occurence of each letter in the sentence, the first 'macavity' has it's own occurences of the letters 'm,a,c,v,i,t,y' yet 'macavity' as a type consists of it' 'own' occurences of those same letters.  I apologise if this is difficult to read

Comment: @Papuseme I think I was confused by what she said in  the reference Mauro made, you are correct.

Comment: @Confused in response to updated OP, where does wetzel claim that expressions are "sequences of sequences"?

Comment: @Papuseme This what I took from it when she described to have 'occurences' is to be a part of a sequence and then states that expressions can have occurences in others. This is written explictly on page 218: , the same letter or word type can occur twice in a sequence that is an expression type; * consists of seven words in that it is a sequence of length seven, each member of which is a word type.'

Comment: @Confused on page 219, she defines what she means by x occurs in y at least n times. This definition does not imply that expressions are now sequences of sequences. Instead, expressions (in her terminology) are still sequences of letters.

Comment: Yeah, I see that I may have confused myself  however how does this new idea of 'occurence' work? If not as a sequence? She used the idea of a sequence to define her 'occurences', are they of a different type?

Comment: @Confused I think it would be best if you read over page 219 again, she explains it in her own words quite clearly. The notion of sequence remains the same.